# how to create a folder on desktop everytime a new user is created?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, active-directory, windows-7

How can I configure the system so that whenever I create a new user,  and automatically available on her/his desktop a directory called "project"?.
Is there something related to  C:\Users\Default??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Just create a folder within the `C:\Users\Default\Desktop` directory.

Note that this folder will only be created when the user logs into the machine (i.e. via RDP), and the folder will only exist *locally* (i.e. on the machine itself).

Comment: `Note that this folder will only be created when the user logs into the machine locally (i.e. via RDP)` - That doesn't quite make sense. Logging on via RDP isn't considered to be logging on locally. In fact, there are two specific user rights governing logging on to a Windows machine: `Allow log on locally` and `Allow log on through Remote Desktop Services`.

Comment: @joeqwerty good point, answer edited :)

Comment: You're quick! :)